# Accepting arguments with Cocoa and running system commands

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I am new to Cocoa and Xcode, but I really do want to learn. The problem is that I spend a lot of my time doing work in scripting languages like PHP, perl, python, and shell scripting, and while Cocoa is a lot more powerful than running a shell script in Terminal on OS X, it is also a bit harder to get into.

I have a hypothesis though: If I can start using Cocoa and Xcode to actually do some things then I'll get more comfortable with it and gradually start to unlock more and more of it's potential.

That's where I hope StackOverflow comes in. See, I'm used to writing scripts that take paramaters (mostly file names) as inputs, and act on them - either dispatching other programs or reading and writing to the text-based contents. So with that in mind, **How can I write a simple Cocoa application that will accept input, save that input to a file, and launch a system command?**

Desired input:

```
open -a MyApp.app --args "hello world"
```

Desired output:

- File `/tmp/test.txt` is created and now contains text `hello world`
- The php version is checked by running `/usr/bin/php -v` and the output is then appended to `/tmp/test.txt` (just wanted to call some system command)

I know this sort of thing is very easy to do with just 1-2 lines of something like bash scripting, but I'd really like to see if I could make this happen in a Cocoa app. I apologize in advance because I realize this is very much a noob question - just trying to get started in a way that feels familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process command-line arguments and have a GUI, you'll definitely want to look at [NSProcessInfo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Among other things, it has a method called `arguments` that returns the command-line args as an `NSArray`.

It can also give you an `NSDictionary` of environment variables, which can also be really useful, from the `environment` method.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, if you want to save the contents of a string to file, `NSString` already has a method for that! Look at the docs for `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a purely input/output type of application that doesn't have an UI, just write a straight Unix-style application in C/C++/Objective-C (whichever you prefer).  Your program's arguments will show up in the `argc` and `argv` parameters that get passed to your `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // argc is the total number of arguments (including the program name)
    // argv[0] is the first argument (the program name)
    // argv[1] is the second argument (first real argument)
    // ...
    // argv[argc-1] is the last argument
}
```

If you do have a real UI, typically the `main` function is autogenerated by Xcode and placed in a file named `main.m`—it's a stub function that calls `NSApplicationMain` with an autorelease pool around it.  You can modify this to save off `argc` and `argv` and/or process them right there.

Comment: Great! Got it working! Who more questions: How do I call a system command, and how could I do something like `std::cout << argv[*];` to echo all of the arguments at once?

Comment: @cwd: Please ask separate questions for those, but the short answers are [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) and [`ostream_iterator`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ostream_iterator.html).